# Why dp, px, mm looks different in different android phones

Tags: android, android-layout

Every time when I have to set width, height, margin, padding, etc of widget or layout i think which unit would looks same in all android phones. I have tried all these units in my different apps. But there are many devices where your 5dp seems 10dp or more. I have read many articles, blogs and stackoverflow  posts about screen densities that describes all phones have different screen densities thats why dp looks different in different phones. But mm and cm are physical units. So they should be look same in different phones. But they also not working like physical units. So my question is there any way that we can use these units or any new that look same in all mobile phones?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Comment: dp stands for `density-independent pixel that corresponds to the physical size of a pixel`. This is the unit you should use as default.The main issue with "wrong sizes" are that manufacturers are "lying" about what their devices actually are. As far as I know, there is no "fix", just good ROMs that understand their actual device, and bad ROMs.

Comment: @bonatti I am aware of dp. But why physical units like mm or cm looks different

Comment: Because the manufacturer of that device has not set the actual, real size of the screen that the device has. [This can you show you](https://design.google.com/devices/) some common sizes, as well as the ammount of resolution in regards to screen size. As far as most ROMs (the Android installed) goes, it is expected that they use the actual info on the device, and not a "pre-set" one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right. But is there any way ?  There should be something using which we can fix this. I have never seen such issues in apps like Facebook , WhatsApp, etc

Comment: It is recommended to use dp, the reasons are explained here https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I know it recommended. But practically we all know how it looks in different phones. Even I have names of devices on which you can clearly see the huge differences.

Comment: Well, this is why you must provide different layouts. Or different dimensions for the same layouts. Your choice.

Comment: Is this the only way that we test our app on every device and write separate layout for them ???

Comment: different layouts or different dimens. your choice. Or you could (but would be an overkill and I don't encourage you to) do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

There are different reasons, one been the quantity of pixels within a particular screen referred as dpi (dots per inch). "low" density screens have fewer pixels within a given physical area, compared to a "normal" or "high" density screen.

It also has to do whit orientation, either landscape or portrait, meaning that the screen's aspect ratio is either wide or tall.

You can get more insight on the matter here: [Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: But what about the physical units like mm and cm?  They are independent of screen specifications. I am looking for the answer. Exact answer.